# Fast processing of large tables and table columns - apply too slow

Tags: r, performance, apply

I have been using R for a long time now, and I have working code for a specific little task. But I was wondering if there is any faster solution.

The problem is simple: I have a data frame `tbl` with two columns `ID` and `NrBlocks`. IDs are not unique and may appear multiple times, but with the same or different `NrBlocks`. The table has more columns in reality but these details are irrelevant here. All I want is the sum of the `NrBlocks` values for each unique `ID`.

Working code (before renaming, I hope I did not introduce typos due to the simplification here):

```
uniqueIDs = unique(tbl$ID) #Precompute once
sapply(1:length(uniqueIDs),
       FUN = function(x){
         sum(tbl[which(tbl$ID == uniqueIDs[x]),]$NrBlocks)
       }
)
```

Any suggestions for a speed improvement?

Comment: Sounds like a straight-up aggregation.  `aggregate(value ~ ID, data, sum)`

Comment: @RichardScriven, he asked for a fast solution :)

Comment: Thanks so much, exactly what I was looking for. Why did I never stumble upon the aggregate function? You made my day. Seems to be faster than my previous solution, but maybe there is an even faster variant?

Comment: @DavidArenburg you don't think aggregate would be faster?

Comment: @RichardScriven, it will be faster than his solution for sure, but it will be the slowest solution out of all the "standard" aggregation possibilities

Comment: You guys and your obsession with speed. We're often talking about fractions of a second.  I don't think it really matters, as long as I get the correct result.  Plus, it could cancel out if you consider the time spent learning how to loop something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obligatory `data.table` solution -

```
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
library(data.table)
##
set.seed(1234)
dTbl <- data.table(
  ID = sample(c(letters,LETTERS),100000,replace=TRUE),
  NrBlocks = rnorm(100000),
  key = "ID")
##
gTbl <- dTbl[
  ,
  list(sumNrBlocks = sum(NrBlocks)),
  by = list(ID)]
##
> head(gTbl)
   ID sumNrBlocks
1:  A    56.50234
2:  B   -13.61380
3:  C    24.66750
4:  D    65.18829
5:  E    26.14085
6:  F    41.64376
```

**Timings:**

```
library(microbenchmark)
##
uniqueIDs <- unique(dTbl$ID)
f1 <- function(){
  sapply(1:length(uniqueIDs),
         FUN = function(x){
           sum(dTbl[which(dTbl$ID == uniqueIDs[x]),]$NrBlocks)
         }
  )
}
##
f2 <- function(){
  dTbl[
    ,
    list(sumNrBlocks = sum(NrBlocks)),
    by = list(ID)]
}
##
Res <- microbenchmark(
  f1(),
  f2(),
  times=100L)
Res
> Res
Unit: milliseconds
 expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
 f1() 139.054620 141.534227 144.213253 156.747569 193.278071   100
 f2()   1.813652   1.911069   1.980874   2.140971   3.522545   100
```

**Multiple columns:**

```
dTbl2 <- copy(dTbl)
set.seed(1234)
dTbl2[,col3:=rexp(100000)]
dTbl2[,col4:=col3*2]
##
gTbl2 <- dTbl2[
  ,
  lapply(.SD,sum),
  by=list(ID)]
##
> head(gTbl2)
   ID  NrBlocks     col3     col4
1:  A  56.50234 1933.443 3866.886
2:  B -13.61380 1904.282 3808.563
3:  C  24.66750 1834.655 3669.310
4:  D  65.18829 1884.364 3768.728
5:  E  26.14085 1874.761 3749.523
6:  F  41.64376 1977.219 3954.438
```

**Multiple columns with specification -**

```
gTbl2.2 <- dTbl2[
  ,
  lapply(.SD,sum),
  by=list(ID),
  .SDcols=c(2,4)]
##
> head(gTbl2.2)
   ID  NrBlocks     col4
1:  A  56.50234 3866.886
2:  B -13.61380 3808.563
3:  C  24.66750 3669.310
4:  D  65.18829 3768.728
5:  E  26.14085 3749.523
6:  F  41.64376 3954.438
```

Comment: Wow thanks didn't know about this, I will test it right away. Thanks nrussell for your help, greatly appreciated!

Comment: No problem - `data.table` is a really useful package.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 500 milliseconds to spare, you can do this with `aggregate` in one easy line.

```
aggregate(NrBlocks ~ ID, dat, mean)
microbenchmark(aggregate(NrBlocks ~ ID, dat, mean))
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#   f() 655.218 655.6562 656.6428 661.6947 667.0888   100
```

Where `dat` is a data frame created from nrussell's table.

```
dim(dat)
# [1] 10000 2
```